# AppSync mapping response from Lambda getting result from ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-lambda, aws-appsync, aws-cloud9

I am trying to invoke a lambda function from AppSync passing a search query. The lambda is calling elastic search which returns the result set.

I am able to map the result set to different fields in the graphQL Schama

```
$#set($result = {
   "statusCode": "${context.result.statusCode}",
   "headers": "${context.result.headers}",
   "isBase64Encoded": "${context.result.isBase64Encoded}",
   "body": "${context.result.body}"
})
$util.toJson($result)
```

In body get the search result set which I need to then parse and map them to a Schama.

I am unable to extract the response ${context.result.body.hits.hits} to iterate through the _source and set the search result set

Any suggestion and guidance will very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

AppSync has built in support for Amazon Elasticsearch resolvers. You can find some more information about that [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-elasticsearch-resolvers.html)!

However, if you wish to keep your current Lambda resolver you could try the following mapping template:

```js
## Delcare an empty array
#set( $result = [] )

## Loop through results
#foreach($entry in $context.result.hits.hits)   

    ## Add each item to the result array
    $util.qr($result.add(
    {
        'id' : $entry.get("_source")['id'],
        'title' : $entry.get("_source")['fields']['title'],
        'plot' : $entry.get("_source")['fields']['plot'],
        'year' : $entry.get("_source")['fields']['year'],
        'url' : $entry.get("_source")['fields']['image_url']
    }))

#end

## Parse the result
$util.toJson($result)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by converting the context results body as below. Once this was done , I was able to iterate the resultSet

```
[
#set($result = $context.result)

## resultSet - parse back to JSON
#set($result.resultSet = $util.parseJson($context.result.body))

#foreach($entry in $result.resultSet.hits.hits)

    ## $velocityCount starts at 1 and increments with the #foreach loop **
    #if( $velocityCount > 1 ) , #end

    $util.toJson(
        {
        'id' : $entry.get("_source")['id'],
        'title' : $entry.get("_source")['fields']['title'],
        'plot' : $entry.get("_source")['fields']['plot'],
        'year' : $entry.get("_source")['fields']['year'],
        'url' : $entry.get("_source")['fields']['image_url']
        }
    )

#end
]
```